# \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article} not working properly

Tags: paper-size, article

I'm using `\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}` in my TeX file. It all works fine, except, the lower bound of each page is cut off. So some text is either cut off, or at least the text reaches the very end of the page.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Here is an minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\setlength{\headheight}{12.4pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.5\headheight}

\begin{document}

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f

\section{a}

asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f
asdlkjf sakfj saoekfsalk lksa jfsakfsaoel jfsaoelkfj saoeflksad jfoelksaf sadfoelkjsa f


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The interesting fact is, that on another Computer the bounds are getting displayed the right way, without changing anything in the Tex-File.

Comment: What means "on another computer"? What is the configuration of the machine  (operating system, tex distribution,..) that is not working and on which configuration is it working?

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 (with default Tex), it is not working properly, on Ubuntu 13.04 it does work properly.

Comment: Your example (which isn't exactly _minimal_), doesn't have anything between ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``, so there won't be any output at all.

Comment: output added, example is now more minimized

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `TeX` distribution probably has a default paper size setting that is not A4. Unfortunately, specifying paper size as an option to the document class won't always override this default. Specifically, `dvips` won't know about the option, and the equivalent part of `pdfTeX` won't know about it either (the standard document classes predate `pdfTeX`). The simplest solution is to use the geometry package.

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

This sets the variables `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` for pdfTeX, and in dvi mode it inserts specials that tell `dvips` about the size of the paper.

Comment: `geometry` should be loaded before `fullpage`.